# jquery get all id elements with type file

Tags: jquery

I have form:

```
<form id="formUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="file" id="TextFile" name="TextFile">
    <input type="file" id="ImageFile" name="ImageFile">
    <input type="file" id="f2" name="f2">
    <input type="submit" id="sub">
</form>
```

I want to apend all my files to FormData:

```
$('#input:file').each(function() {
    fd.append(this.id, document.getElementById(this.id).files[0]);
});
```

But this doesn't work. How can I get all ids from element with type file?

Comment: Your selector is saying give me the element with the `id="input"` and is a file

Comment: `input:file` would suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[type='file']").each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
  });
});
```

This will return you all ids with input type = "file".

Fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/o68uhb8p/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
var file = 
$('input[type=file]').map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get();
console.log(file);// this will print all the ids of type file
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="TextFile" name="TextFile">
<input type="file" id="ImageFile" name="ImageFile">
<input type="file" id="f2" name="f2">
```